# Local character expansion for discrete series representations of $GL_n(F)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, rt.representation-theory, p-adic-groups

I'm interested about what, if anything, is known about the local character expansion of discrete-series representations of $GL_n(F)$, where $F$ is a $p$-adic field.

First, some notation: let $G$ be a reductive group over a $p$-adic field $F$ and let $\pi$ be an admissible $G(F)$ representation (throughout, we'll assume $\pi$ irreducible).  Let $\Theta_{\pi}$ be its character. It's a result of Harish-Chandra that, for all regular elements $X$ in a suitably small of neighborhood of the identity in the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, we have
$$\Theta_{\pi}(\exp X) = \sum_{\mathcal{O}} c_{\mathcal{O}}(\pi) \hat\mu_{\mathcal{O}}(X);$$
here the sum runs over nilpotent orbits $\mathcal{O}$ in $\mathfrak{g}$, and $\hat \mu_{\mathcal{O}}$ is Harish-Chandra's locally-integrable function representing the linear functional
$$f \mapsto \mu_{\mathcal{O}}(\hat f),$$
and $\mu_{\mathcal{O}}(h)$ denotes the orbital integral of $h$ over the orbit $\mathcal{O}$.

Now let $G = GL_n$.  If $\pi$ is supercuspidal, then the constants $c_{\mathcal{O}}$ have been computed explicitly: Murnaghan constructs a regular elliptic element $X_{\pi}$ such that 
$$c_{\mathcal{O}}(\pi) = \hat \mu_{\mathcal{O}}(X_\pi).$$

Is anything explicit about these constants known when $\pi$ a (non-supercuspidal) discrete-series representation?

As a somewhat more specific question: in this case, there is a supercuspidal representation $\rho$ of $GL_m(F)$ such that $\pi = Sp(\rho,\, d)$ with $n = md$.  It stands to reason there should be a relationship between the characters of $\pi$ and $\rho$, but I haven't been able to find anything on the subject except in the case where $m = 1$ (so $\rho$ is an abelian character).

For what it's worth, I'm specifically interested in the case where $\rho$ has depth zero, though I'm certainly curious about the general case.

EDIT: a quick note.  When $\pi = Sp(\rho, d)$, then $\pi$ is a subquotient of $I_{P}^G \rho'$, where $\rho'$ is the supercuspidal representation of $M = GL_{m}(F)^d$, and 
$$\rho' = \left(\rho|\det|^{(1-d)/2}\right) \otimes \left(\rho|\det|^{(3-d)/2} \right)\otimes \ldots \otimes \left(\rho|\det|^{(d-1)/2}\right).$$

We can directly read off the character of $I_P^G(\rho')$ from that of $\rho$, and $\pi$ is the unique generic subquotient of $I_P^G(\rho')$, so we can read off the coefficent $c_{\mathcal{O}^1}(\pi)$ from the character of $\rho$, where $\mathcal{O}^1$ is the nilpotent orbit of maximal dimension. I'm curious about the other constants.

Comment: $c_0(\pi)$ is the formal degree.  I hate to answer a question by telling you to ask a different one, but are you sure that the LCE is really the right way to look at it?  My impression is that the asymptotic expansions of Kim–Murnaghan ([MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2018660) and [MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2222734)) are the 'right' way to think about them.  Murnaghan has a gorgeous paper computing all the constants in such an expansion on $\operatorname{GL}_n$ by reduction to unipotents ([MR](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1990222)).

Comment: You're absolutely right: you can get much more information out of the local character expansion in terms of Murnaghan's element $c_\pi$.  I asked this question before I was aware of Murnaghan's results (new to the field).  Nonetheless, I haven't responded with an answer to this question because: a) as you noted, it's not exactly an answer to the question and b) I'm a little uncertain of the etiquette of answering one's own question.

Comment: I think that the consensus is that this is perfectly fine; see, for example, http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/730/answering-my-own-question and other results at http://meta.mathoverflow.net/search?q=answer+own+question .